# Are the digits of a number appear in a sequence in a stack?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Given a stack of numbers and an integer, I wish to write a Java method that returns true if all the digits of the number appear as a sequence in a stack, when the stack can be looked at from top to bottom or bottom up.

I wrote a code, but it gives partially bad results.

For example, for the stack [1,2,3] when 3 is the top and the number 12, it gives the wrong result. But for [3,2,1] where 1 is the top it gives the correct result. The problem is somewhere in the reversing of the stack. The "or" operator fails.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: StackX is a class I wrote. It is a stack of numbers, with the common operations: push, pop, peek, isEmpty, isFull and getSize.

My code:

```
// return a string with the stack values
    public static String StackValues(StackX S)
    {
        String seq = "";
        while (!S.isEmpty())
        {
            long l = S.pop();
            seq += Long.toString(l);
        }
        return seq;
    }

    // checks if a string contains a substring
    public static boolean sub(String string, String substring)
    {
        int index = string.indexOf(substring);
        if (index==-1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    // returns a reverse of the string
    public static StackX StackReverse(StackX S)
    {
        StackX newStack = new StackX(S.getStackMaxSize());
        while (!S.isEmpty())
        {
            newStack.push(S.pop());
        }
        return newStack;
    }

    public static boolean isSeq(StackX S, int num)
    {
        String theNum = Integer.toString(num);
        String theStack = StackValues(S);
        StackX temp = new StackX(S.getStackMaxSize());
        temp = StackReverse(S);
        String theStackReversed = StackValues(temp);

        if (sub(theStack, theNum)==true || sub(theStackReversed, theNum)==true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? What are the values of `theStack` and `theStackReversed`?

Comment: I ran a few examples, and it always works fine on one direction only. I have debugged the reverse method and it works.

Comment: `String theStack = StackValues(S);` Doesn't that empty the stack? So `temp = StackReverse(S);` copies an empty stack.

Comment: Oh, I think you are right. I'll check. It makes sense, I have ruined the stack and never restored it.

Comment: You mentioned, _"... all the digits of the number appear as a sequence in a stack"_.  A _sequence_ of numbers is typically just any array, and a _stack_ simply implies a _LIFO_ or _FIFO_ factoring.  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: It is an exercise for learning how to work with stacks. No practical use